# Why does Yasako have an encode reactor?

Tags: dennou-coil

In episode 23 of Dennou Coil, we find out that Yasako (Okonogi Yuko) has a working encode reactor. I think I missed the part where they explain how she got it and whether it's a physical device or a virtual one. Was it something installed into her body (or her virtual private data) during the healing experiment?

Answer (score 2):

In a forum [post](http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?339229-Anime-Dennou-Coil&p=8197494#post8197494) asking the same thing you did,

> So, where did Yasako's encode reactor come from? It can't possibly be from Isako's prior encode; Satchii always chased Yasako even when she was "clean." It must have been built into her glasses from the beginning by the Cyberpappy. Exactly why he felt the need to do this, I don't know.

this was the [reply](http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?339229-Anime-Dennou-Coil&p=8197538#post8197538):

> It came from the kilabug (kirabug?) that Isako transferred while
>   trying to save Haraken.